# Show only content that is visible with in container

Tags: html, css

In the demo below, you can see I have 2 `divs`, one with the text `t` and one with `s`. They are both contained within `.items`

Currently both of those are visible, but I'm trying to create it so that (in this case) only `t` is visible.

**Demo**

```css
.t {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.items {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:-30px;
}

.item{
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      t
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there some css property I can add, so i can achive this?

Comment: Based on what condition do you want to show/hide t?

Comment: @GolezTrol If you look at the example. I wish that only the `item` that is "visible" inside the border to be shown.

Comment: You only want t in container???

Comment: What did i do wrong since i've been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `overflow:hidden` to the parent class `.t`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.t {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: -30px;
}

.item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      t
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      t
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now t  is outside the border

Comment: @PeterHansen Updated...!

Comment: Thats what i want, i just dont feel its that dynamic, what if this is the senario https://jsfiddle.net/otvp9021/

Comment: @PeterHansen in the fiddle what element you want to show

Comment: The one that is visible inside the border, im trying to make it some what dynamic

Comment: @PeterHansen oh that whats you want....no need to use `nth-child`...just put `overflow:hidden` to the parent class....See updated..!

Comment: Just what i wanted, thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think to do that you'll need javascript and Jquery

instead of `css({color: 'red'})` you can add a class `addClass('visible')`

```js
var $t = $('.t');
y = $t.offset().top;
y2 = y + $t.outerHeight(); 

x = $t.offset().left;
x2 = x + $t.outerWidth();


$items = $t.find('.item')
$items.each(function(index, elmt){
  var elmtY = $(elmt).offset().top;
  var elmtY2 = elmtY + $(elmt).outerHeight();
  
  var elmtX = $(elmt).offset().left;
  var elmtX2 = elmtY + $(elmt).outerWidth();
 if(elmtY > y && elmtY2 < y2 && elmtX > x && elmtX2 < x2){
   $(elmt).css({color: 'red'})
  }
});
```

```css
.t {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.items {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:-30px;
}

.item{
  height: 30px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">
      s
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      t
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is a joke, it's brilliant! :)

Comment: Ah, the ol' "use Jquery" answer. SO at it's finest =)

Comment: kkkk I just realize what he wanted after coding kkk

Comment: I thought he wanted to do something just with the elements inside the box

Comment: Yeah, but even then. Looking at the coordinates to check if something is or is not `:nth-child`. Awesome! :-D

Comment: @GolezTrol the 2 letters are children, but just the `t` is inside the box

Comment: @GolezTrol my code is dinamic, if he add or remove letters, just the letters inside the visible area will become red

Comment: @GolezTrol noo man, you don't need to be ironic. This code works If he wants to apply color just for the elements inside the box or if he wants to apply an animation just to the elements inside the box, etc. I didn't realize that he wanted to hide the overflow elements, just after answering